# How to convert a JSON string stored in a Content Document back to a Map and merge it with a Map of similar type?

Tags: apex, contentversion, algorithm

I have a Map of type -

```
Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>> valuesMapOne = new Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>();
```

This Map is serialized and saved into a ContentVersion as -

```
String serializedJson = JSON.serialize(valuesMapOne);
ContentVersion contV = new ContentVersion (
                Title = FieldName,
                PathOnClient = FieldName + '.txt',
                VersionData = Blob.valueOf(serializedJson),
                IsMajorVersion = true
            );
insert contV;
```

There is another Map -

```
Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>> valuesMapTwo = new Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>();
```

I have a requirement to retrieve the previously saved JSON from the ContentVersion later and update it with values contained inside **valuesMapTwo**. When I am trying to read the values from the Blob and trying to convert it to required type it gives a runtime error. -

```
List<ContentVersion> contDoc = [SELECT Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title =: FieldName LIMIT 1];
if (contDoc.size() > 0) {
    Blob existingBlobData = contDoc[0].VersionData;
    String existingJson = existingBlobData.toString();
    Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>> valuesMap = (Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(existingJson);
    valuesMap.putAll(valuesMapTwo);
}
```

Error is -

```
 System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String, ANY> to Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>
```

Is there a way to merge the values of valueMapTwo with the existing JSON from valuesMapOne after retrieval ?

Comment: `Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>> valuesMap = (Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>)JSON.deserialize(existingJson,Map<String,List<List<LineInfo>>>.class);`

Comment: @cropredy It gives a FATAL_ERROR | System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object on using the above

Comment: if LineInfo has a member variable of type Object then this will happen

Comment: Why was this closed - the answer linked above doesn't solve for the user's issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally it would be nice if you could restore the String back to the map using this:

```
Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>> valuesMap = (Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(existingJson);
```

However, as you mentioned, you get `Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String, ANY>` as this deserialization returns `Map<String, Object>`.  You will need to take that Map<String, Object> returned value and break it down back into the original map one part at a time...

```
String existingJson = existingBlobData.toString();
Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>> valuesMap = new Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>();

Map<String, Object> mapResults = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(existingJson);
for ( String k : mapResults.keySet() ) {
    valuesMap.put(k, (List<List<LineInfo>>>)mapResults.get(k));
}
```

Note: If "Object" won't convert directly to `List<List<LineInfo>>>`, then you'll need to further break it apart by assigning `mapResults.get(k)` to a `List<Object>` and then go through each of those objects, converting to `List<Object>` and then go through each of those objects, converting to `LineInfo`.  For the answer here, I did not go to the extent of testing that, but I hope it's clear enough how to do it.

Merging the maps - assuming you just want to replace the existing key values with the new:

```
valuesMap.putAll(valueMapTwo);
```

Note: you may want to wrap the "deserializeUntyped" statement in  try/catch for error handling - it will error if the string does not deserialize into the expected data type.

Comment: I had tried this earlier. It gives - System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to Map<String, List<List<LineInfo>>>. I will update it in my question.

Comment: @KnightoftheVale I updated my response - hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. That was very helpful. Thank you